# AJAX calls server but POST fails (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

just trying to implement a basic ajax request.  the js calls the server and will recieve a response back but now i need to send a parameter to get a specific value back from the server so i send form data via POST.  the PHP script recognizes that a $_POST request was submitted but if i access the data in $_POST i get error "Undefined array key "item""  Any help?  I get one s

```
//javascript script
function doTHIS()
{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('item', 'apple');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200)
        {
    
            document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "ajaxScript.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(data);
}


//php script
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
    if($_POST["item"]=='apple')
        echo "sucess";
    else
        echo "fail";
}
```

I get fail everytime.  I have been reading w3school and various other resources ALL DAY!  I am handling the form data wrong i think but dont see how.  I have varied the syntax 100 different ways.

Comment: Hi its `fname` or `item` ?

Comment: ill edit.  it is correct in my code.  i was trying to change code up for a basic example here.

Comment: do `echo $_POST["item"];` see what it brings back .

Comment: changed the whole php script to this...
<?php echo $POST['item']; ?> 
and get same error.

Comment: same error ? please elaborate what error you are getting ? is there any error in browser console ? is status `200` of ajax call ?

Comment: "Undefined array key "item"" is the error i recieve. Status has to be 200 since that is a condition for sending the request.  The php script is definitely being called upon. I will get a confirmation on status 200 real fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good except FormData object, you are not passing any form element, if you need to send just parameter
use below for creating data & you should be good

var data = 'item=apple&item2=mango';

Comment: worked.  if you have time can you elaborate why my method was wrong and why your method works?  Thanks so much by the way.

Comment: if u need to send whole form with various fields, your method will help you like below


<form id="itemForm">
  <input type="text" name="item" value="Apple">
  <input type="text" name="item2" value="mango">
  <input type="submit">
</form>


And


var data = new FormData( $('#itemForm') );